# Element not appearing when previous elements are different?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code displaying a time next to a flight number. If there are multiple flight numbers to fade through, the time element, is no longer visible, when it is a separate element to what comes before. I cannot see any reason why this is the case.

Code where the time does not display:

```
<div id='fltsmain' class='cell  flts' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
        <div id='flts1' class='cell flts fader1'>LM234</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
        <div id='flts0' class='cell flts fader0'>FR1234</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='cell time'>11:30</div>
```

And code where the time does display:

```
<div class='cell flts' style='background-color:LightSlateGray;'>LG123</div>


<div class='cell time'>11:50</div>
```

And the associated styles:

```
.cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.flts{
    left: 238px;
    width: 250px;
    color: White;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: SkyBlue;
}

.time{
    left: 488px;
    width: 200px;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you should remove the **position: absolute** from the outer div in the first code example, or wrap the flight number and time elements in a parent div with **position: relative** to create a containing block for the **position: absolute** elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should remove the `absolute` position of the element with id `fltsmain`, for the two elements showing the flight numbers only one is showing because of the `absolute` position, I changed it to `relative` to show them two, Apart from that I did some cleaning in you `CSS` as bellow:

```css
.cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 5px;
}

.flts{
    width: 250px;
    color: White;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: SkyBlue;
}

.time{
    width: 200px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='fltsmain' class='cell flts'>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:relative;'>
        <div id='flts1' class='cell flts fader1'>LM234</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:relative;'>
        <div id='flts0' class='cell flts fader0'>FR1234</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='cell time'>11:30</div>
```